# How to solve "ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12.0"

Tags: tensorflow, installation, pip

I am trying to install tensorflow 1.12.0. This is the command that I am using `pip install tensorflow==1.12.0`. I got this command from this [link](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.12.0/). This is the error that I am getting.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow==1.12.0 (from versions: 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2,
> 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12.0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please look carefully at the linked page. In the left column there is a list of Python versions compatible with this TF version. If you want to continue using your current Python version you have to install a different, compatible TF version. If you want to install exactly that TF version you need to install and use a different, compatible Python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My python version was 3.9. Intalling python version 3.6 solved the problem. I installed it in virtual environment with conda.

Answer (score 2):

You can install previous versions of Tensorflow directly from the Github release page. For example, the 1.12.0 version can be downloaded from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.12.0.